# Unable to put dates in a column and metric in another in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, metrics

**Question:** For a given day t, I need to create an on-time delivery (OTD) metric for 61 days for seller_id "123".
The OTD is the rate at which packages were delivered on-time
for packages created in the 30 days preceding t.
Not only do we want to know today's OTD, but we want to know the OTD for
every date in the past 60 days.

```
CREATE TABLE `packages` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `seller_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `promise_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivered_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `packages` (`id`, `created_at`, `seller_id`, `promise_date`, `delivered_at`) VALUES
('1', '2020-04-15 06:26:28', '246', '2020-04-20', '2020-04-20 07:47:07'),
('2', '2020-05-02 06:19:13', '123', '2020-05-06', '2020-05-07 07:01:26'),
('3', '2020-07-05 08:47:17', '789', '2020-07-08', '2020-07-09 08:22:08'),
('4', '2020-03-25 08:12:35', '234', '2020-03-30', '2020-03-30 08:49:50'),
('5', '2020-07-01 07:51:33', '789', '2020-07-06', '2020-07-06 08:34:48'),
('6', '2020-03-01 08:11:31', '123', '2020-03-04', '2020-03-04 06:00:14'),
('7', '2020-05-20 07:38:14', '246', '2020-05-25', '2020-05-25 08:13:51'),
('8', '2020-04-14 07:30:19', '123', '2020-04-17', '2020-04-17 07:46:55'),
('9', '2020-02-10 08:53:00', '234', '2020-02-13', '2020-02-14 06:45:57'),
('10', '2020-01-21 07:14:56', '246', '2020-01-24', '2020-01-25 08:03:04'),
('11', '2020-07-03 08:05:11', '123', '2020-07-08', '2020-07-09 08:30:56'),
('12', '2020-05-09 06:18:31', '789', '2020-05-13', '2020-05-13 08:38:55'),
('13', '2020-02-13 08:11:10', '123', '2020-02-18', '2020-02-18 07:48:52'),
('14', '2020-04-28 08:25:28', '789', '2020-05-01', '2020-05-02 06:06:32'),
('15', '2020-06-02 07:28:52', '234', '2020-06-05', '2020-06-06 07:29:43'),
('16', '2020-05-04 08:39:33', '123', '2020-05-07', '2020-05-08 06:33:14'),
('17', '2020-07-26 08:18:30', '789', '2020-07-29', '2020-07-30 07:28:53'),
('18', '2020-02-25 08:37:42', '234', '2020-02-28', '2020-02-29 06:05:23'),
('19', '2020-02-03 06:55:39', '234', '2020-02-06', '2020-02-07 07:18:28'),
('20', '2020-03-07 08:20:44', '246', '2020-03-11', '2020-03-11 08:11:45'),
('21', '2020-03-11 07:19:47', '789', '2020-03-16', '2020-03-16 06:55:46'),
('22', '2020-06-24 08:18:56', '789', '2020-06-29', '2020-06-29 08:47:59'),
('23', '2020-02-25 07:24:19', '123', '2020-02-28', '2020-02-28 06:54:57'),
('24', '2020-07-12 07:51:52', '789', '2020-07-15', '2020-07-16 07:36:21'),
('25', '2020-01-26 07:44:59', '234', '2020-01-29', '2020-01-29 08:52:24'),
('26', '2020-02-07 06:09:24', '246', '2020-02-12', '2020-02-13 08:16:37'),
('27', '2020-03-11 08:34:57', '123', '2020-03-16', '2020-03-17 08:33:47'),
('28', '2020-02-24 08:15:41', '789', '2020-02-27', '2020-02-27 06:19:59'),
('29', '2020-02-02 06:45:36', '123', '2020-02-05', '2020-02-06 06:22:25'),
('30', '2020-02-10 06:51:48', '123', '2020-02-13', '2020-02-13 06:45:07'),
('31', '2020-03-27 07:11:58', '789', '2020-04-01', '2020-04-02 08:55:56'),
('32', '2020-05-31 07:10:05', '246', '2020-06-03', '2020-06-03 08:56:47'),
('33', '2020-06-28 06:14:19', '789', '2020-07-01', '2020-07-02 06:35:18'),
('34', '2020-07-08 08:30:12', '789', '2020-07-13', '2020-07-14 06:06:09'),
('35', '2020-05-13 08:13:34', '123', '2020-05-18', '2020-05-18 08:24:42'),
('36', '2020-04-19 08:13:38', '246', '2020-04-22', '2020-04-22 07:32:14'),
('37', '2020-03-02 06:57:32', '234', '2020-03-05', '2020-03-05 07:16:05'),
('38', '2020-05-22 08:49:51', '246', '2020-05-27', '2020-05-27 06:47:41'),
('39', '2020-02-27 08:18:26', '123', '2020-03-03', '2020-03-03 06:32:56'),
('40', '2020-02-17 07:10:24', '246', '2020-02-20', '2020-02-21 06:06:26'),
('41', '2020-06-25 08:29:32', '234', '2020-06-30', '2020-06-30 07:37:07'),
('42', '2020-03-02 08:07:57', '234', '2020-03-05', '2020-03-05 08:41:13'),
('43', '2020-06-18 06:44:38', '234', '2020-06-23', '2020-06-23 06:11:26'),
('44', '2020-07-15 08:22:49', '246', '2020-07-20', '2020-07-20 08:34:28'),
('45', '2020-07-07 07:54:10', '123', '2020-07-10', '2020-07-10 07:50:24'),
('46', '2020-07-17 07:43:08', '123', '2020-07-22', '2020-07-22 06:33:22'),
('47', '2020-04-01 08:24:20', '234', '2020-04-06', '2020-04-06 06:12:55'),
('48', '2020-05-14 08:49:10', '123', '2020-05-19', '2020-05-20 06:53:50'),
('49', '2020-06-11 08:20:35', '246', '2020-06-16', '2020-06-16 06:21:10'),
('50', '2020-06-24 06:39:29', '789', '2020-06-29', '2020-06-30 06:03:48'),
('51', '2020-02-29 06:43:01', '246', '2020-03-04', '2020-03-05 07:57:51'),
('52', '2020-07-17 08:23:46', '246', '2020-07-22', '2020-07-22 07:49:01'),
('53', '2020-03-27 07:45:10', '123', '2020-04-01', '2020-04-02 06:43:34'),
('54', '2020-04-28 06:39:55', '246', '2020-05-01', '2020-05-01 08:59:08'),
('55', '2020-05-21 07:16:03', '789', '2020-05-26', '2020-05-26 06:29:53'),
('56', '2020-02-10 08:22:04', '246', '2020-02-13', '2020-02-14 06:24:17'),
('57', '2020-02-02 08:04:26', '234', '2020-02-05', '2020-02-05 08:59:43'),
('58', '2020-03-02 08:21:53', '246', '2020-03-05', '2020-03-06 08:45:36'),
('59', '2020-02-19 08:37:15', '123', '2020-02-24', '2020-02-24 08:24:44'),
('60', '2020-06-16 08:51:24', '234', '2020-06-19', '2020-06-20 08:25:14'),
('61', '2020-07-11 07:37:15', '234', '2020-07-15', '2020-07-15 07:03:13'),
('62', '2020-06-15 07:56:39', '123', '2020-06-18', '2020-06-19 07:11:16'),
('63', '2020-03-06 07:21:52', '123', '2020-03-11', '2020-03-11 07:46:48'),
('64', '2020-06-03 06:43:50', '789', '2020-06-08', '2020-06-09 07:40:17'),
('65', '2020-01-20 06:28:47', '234', '2020-01-23', '2020-01-24 08:34:05'),
('66', '2020-04-02 08:04:41', '123', '2020-04-07', '2020-04-08 08:56:45'),
('67', '2020-03-04 06:05:57', '789', '2020-03-09', '2020-03-10 06:26:56'),
('68', '2020-07-04 06:47:46', '246', '2020-07-08', '2020-07-09 06:53:02'),
('69', '2020-02-25 06:47:09', '246', '2020-02-28', '2020-02-28 07:55:25'),
('70', '2020-02-04 07:17:28', '123', '2020-02-07', '2020-02-07 08:07:54'),
('71', '2020-06-15 07:18:16', '789', '2020-06-18', '2020-06-19 06:02:08'),
('72', '2020-07-09 06:32:34', '234', '2020-07-14', '2020-07-14 08:15:02'),
('73', '2020-05-21 06:12:52', '789', '2020-05-26', '2020-05-27 07:39:20'),
('74', '2020-05-24 06:38:49', '789', '2020-05-27', '2020-05-27 06:51:35'),
('75', '2020-02-27 06:31:02', '123', '2020-03-03', '2020-03-03 08:56:26'),
('76', '2020-07-02 08:55:00', '123', '2020-07-07', '2020-07-07 07:42:16'),
('77', '2020-06-30 06:52:27', '246', '2020-07-03', '2020-07-03 07:43:20'),
('78', '2020-04-25 08:08:14', '246', '2020-04-29', '2020-04-29 07:21:23'),
('79', '2020-06-24 08:34:43', '234', '2020-06-29', '2020-06-30 06:43:59'),
('80', '2020-05-13 08:59:11', '246', '2020-05-18', '2020-05-18 07:19:06'),
('81', '2020-02-21 07:14:16', '789', '2020-02-26', '2020-02-27 07:10:39'),
('82', '2020-06-04 08:43:13', '789', '2020-06-09', '2020-06-09 07:24:28'),
('83', '2020-07-04 07:14:42', '234', '2020-07-08', '2020-07-09 07:45:59'),
('84', '2020-05-24 08:17:00', '246', '2020-05-27', '2020-05-27 06:31:15'),
('85', '2020-03-07 07:43:27', '123', '2020-03-11', '2020-03-12 08:39:45');



create table dates(
fulldate date);

INSERT INTO `dates` (`fulldate`) VALUES
('2020-08-01'),
('2020-07-31'),
('2020-07-30'),
('2020-07-29'),
('2020-07-28'),
('2020-07-27'),
('2020-07-26'),
('2020-07-25'),
('2020-07-24'),
('2020-07-23'),
('2020-07-22'),
('2020-07-21'),
('2020-07-20'),
('2020-07-19'),
('2020-07-18'),
('2020-07-17'),
('2020-07-16'),
('2020-07-15'),
('2020-07-14'),
('2020-07-13'),
('2020-07-12'),
('2020-07-11'),
('2020-07-10'),
('2020-07-09'),
('2020-07-08'),
('2020-07-07'),
('2020-07-06'),
('2020-07-05'),
('2020-07-04'),
('2020-07-03'),
('2020-07-02'),
('2020-07-01'),
('2020-06-30'),
('2020-06-29'),
('2020-06-28'),
('2020-06-27'),
('2020-06-26'),
('2020-06-25'),
('2020-06-24'),
('2020-06-23'),
('2020-06-22'),
('2020-06-21'),
('2020-06-20'),
('2020-06-19'),
('2020-06-18'),
('2020-06-17'),
('2020-06-16'),
('2020-06-15'),
('2020-06-14'),
('2020-06-13'),
('2020-06-12'),
('2020-06-11'),
('2020-06-10'),
('2020-06-09'),
('2020-06-08'),
('2020-06-07'),
('2020-06-06'),
('2020-06-05'),
('2020-06-04'),
('2020-06-03'),
('2020-06-02');
```

**Desired Output:**

```
date       | on_time_delivery_ratio

2020-07-31 | 0.75  
2020-07-30 | 0.69  
2020-07-29 | 0.68  
2020-07-28 | 0.80  
2020-07-27 | 0.79  
2020-07-26 | 0.78  
2020-07-25 | 0.69  
2020-07-24 | 0.72
```

**What I have done:**
I have been able to create a metric, however just for the current date.

```
SELECT curdate(),sum(case when promise_date=date(delivered_at) then 1 else 0 end)/count(*)*100 
 "On-Time Delivery Rate (%)"
from packages p 
where p.seller_id=123 and date(created_at) between DATE_SUB(curdate(),interval 30 day) and 
DATE_SUB(curdate(),interval 1 day);
```

**Where I need help:**
Instead of using curdate(), **I need the dates** from the dates table as the first column of the desired output and the metric for those dates.

**SQL Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b665ca1/2

Comment: You can join package table with Date table to get the date fields from there instead of using `curdate()`

Comment: Thanks for commenting Abhijeet. I have already done that but if you see in my code, in the 4th line, you'd see  "between DATE_SUB(curdate()" , here instead of curdate, I am not able to use/refer the date column. I would appreciate if you could write the code. Thank you

Comment: Can you please create a sql fiddle for this?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b665ca1/2
Here it is Abhijeet, hope this would help.

Comment: `for every date in the past 60 days` - to which are date are you referring here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b665ca1/7 (based on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b665ca1/2 )

```
SELECT 
   delivered_at,
   sum(case when promise_date=date(delivered_at) then 1 else 0 end)/count(*)  "On-Time Delivery Rate (%)"
from packages p 
where p.seller_id=123 
  and date(delivered_at) between DATE_SUB(curdate(),interval 30 day) and DATE_SUB(curdate(),interval 1 day)
group by delivered_at;
```

output:

```
delivered_at    On-Time Delivery Rate (%)
2020-07-07T07:42:16Z    1
2020-07-09T08:30:56Z    0
2020-07-10T07:50:24Z    1
2020-07-22T06:33:22Z    1
```

EDIT: to select the last 61 days

```
SELECT date.d,sum(case when promise_date=date(delivered_at) then 1 else 0 end)/count(*)*100 
 "On-Time Delivery Rate (%)"
from date 
CROSS JOIN packages p 
where p.seller_id=123 
  and date(created_at) between DATE_SUB(date.d,interval 30 day) and DATE_SUB(date.d,interval 1 day)
  and date.d >= DATE_SUB(curdate(),interval 61 day)
GROUP BY date.d
ORDER BY date.d;
```

- I change the `curdate()` from your query to the value date.d.
- `select * from date` should give all dates, at least from the last 61 days.

Comment: Hi Luuk, thanks for answering but this is not what I am looking for actually. In the first column of the output which is date, it should come from the date table because we need the OTD for today and 60 days before today. So, we would have 61 rows in total and delivered_at here is not correct.

Comment: Hey Luuk, this works. Appreciate your time. I have a quick question though. I really want to understand in simple terms what "cross join" with "group by" did here. Could you explain please?

Comment: The CROSS JOIN clause does not have a join predicate. In other words, it does not have the ON or USING clause.  [more info](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cross-join/).   A `GROUP BY` is pretty standard SQL, the combination of `CROSS JOIN` and `GROUP BY` is combining these things. (or do i misunderstand your question? .)

Comment: Thanks for replying Luuk. I do know what is cross join and group by but I just wanted a simple explanation of how the combination of these two worked out in this specific situation to get us the desired output.

Comment: The result(s) from the `CROSS JOIN` should be seen as  result. On this result the `GROUP BY` is applied.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get percentage on OTD for all the dates in `dates table`  where and get the metrics for respective days.
So percentage is calculated as : ((no of on time deliveries between last 30 days  and day before the date) / (total no of deliveries between last 30 days and day before the date))*100;

So if you took example of date 2020-06-02 there are total 3 deliveries happened between 2020-05-02 to 2020-06-01 out of which 1 delivery is on time therefore OTD percentage = 33.3

According to what i have understood, Here is a solution you may be looking for:

Please check [SQL fiddle:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b665ca1/31)

```
SELECT d.fulldate,sum(case when promise_date = date(delivered_at) 
                      and p.seller_id = 123 and date(created_at) between DATE_SUB(d.fulldate,interval 30 day) and 
DATE_SUB(d.fulldate,interval 1 day) then 1 else 0 end)/sum(case when date(created_at) between DATE_SUB(d.fulldate,interval 30 day) and 
DATE_SUB(d.fulldate,interval 1 day) and p.seller_id = 123 then 1 else 0 end)*100
"On-Time Delivery Rate (%)"
from packages p, dates d group by d.fulldate;
where p.seller_id=123 and date(created_at) between DATE_SUB(d.fulldate,interval 30 day) and 
DATE_SUB(d.fulldate,interval 1 day);
```

**Output:**

Below is partial output: (for full output you can check Fiddle given above the query)

```
fulldate    On-Time Delivery Rate (%)
2020-06-02  33.3333
2020-06-03  33.3333
2020-06-04  50
2020-06-05  50
2020-06-06  50
2020-06-07  50
```

Comment: Thanks for taking out time to work on this Abhijeet; seems like the solution has got a bit convoluted. Could you please explain how cross join with group by works here?